# Debian 9. Sound works only ~17sec

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio

I have Debian 9 with Gnome on my Asus A52JT laptop. Sound works well in headphones, but in speakers only first ~17 seconds

```
~$ uname -a
 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`pulseaudio -v` log [here](https://nofile.io/f/pepyuXc0Bm1/pa.log)

Comment: Welcome , please run `pulseaudio -k` (as user)  then `sudo modprobe -rv snd_hda_intel` and `sudo modprobe -v snd_hda_intel`  , `pulseaudio --start`

Comment: @GAD3R I get `modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.` on `sudo modprobe -rv snd_hda_intel` even with `-f` flag

Answer (score 0):

Check that your configuration its un-muted in pavucontrol, also check if there is conflict

```
lspci
```

and look for the sound part to look if tehre is a driver/hardware conflict

Comment: all devices/channels unmuted
`lspci` output [here](https://nofile.io/f/fxHM4GpEV9V/lspci.txt)